# How to set timeval to a random time

Tags: c, time, timeout, libevent, timeval

I am using libevent to do some tasks after some timeouts, timeouts are randomly selected, and each time they change. The problem is I cannot set timeval variable to a random time.

```
int TIMEOUT = 2000000; // 2 millions micro seconds, which is 2 seconds
int mytimeout = (rand() % TIMEOUT) + 1; // a random time between 0 and 2 seconds
int mysec = mytime/1000000; // the number of seconds
int myMicroSec = mytime -  mysec * 1000000; // the number of micro seconds
static struct timeval poll_interval_tv = {mysec, myMicroSec};

myevent = event_new(libevent_get_base(), -1,EV_TIMEOUT,
                        mycallback_function, arg);
```

It returns these errors:
error: initializer element is not constant
error: (near initialization for ‘poll_interval_tv.tv_sec’)

Comment: I'm quite sure that `static` is definitely not what you want there. And it happens to be what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: @Art, thanks you were right, now it works

Comment: @schil227: my int size is 4 bytes, it will cover that

Comment: Ah -  forgive my assumption.

Comment: @MOH: Relying unnecessarily on implementation-specifics if bad style. Use a type with guanteed minimum or fixed width like `int_least32_t` or `int32_t`. If not anything else, you document that you thought about the required range.

Comment: @Olaf: thanks for the advice